# Count the occurrences of a child component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a single file component like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <template v-if="offers.length > 3">
            <a href="#">View all offers here</a>
        </template>

        <template v-else-if="offers.length > 1">
            <offer v-for="offer in offers" :data="offer"></offer>
        </template>

        <template v-else-if="offers.length == 1">
            <offer :title="The offer" :data="offers[0]"></offer>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

Based on the number of `offers`, I choose how many to render.

**Question:** How do I efficiently get/count the number of `<offer>` components? I also need that number to be reactive.

Comment: The fact that this is not easy should make you wonder if you're doing it wrong. If you try and encapsulate state in vue components, you're going to have a miserable life. Vue components want to be stateless interfaces to a store. Offers *should be* in a store in window scope. @DerekFulginiti's downvoted answer is spot on. Get your state out of your components and your problem just goes away. Insist on doing it this way and your problems are just starting.

Comment: Wouldn't a computed property with `return offers.length > 3 ? 0 : offers.length` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no clean way how.

You could count the children of the current instance that are of a specific type. But you would have to call the "recount" logic on `update` hook (as well as `mounted`).

Example:

```js
Vue.component('offer', {
  name: 'Offer',
  template: '<span> offer </span>'
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    offers: [1, 2],
    offerCount: 0
  },
  methods: {
    updateOfferCount() {
      this.offerCount = this.$children.filter(child => child.constructor.options.name === 'Offer').length;
    }
  },
  updated() {
    this.updateOfferCount()
  },
  mounted() {
    this.updateOfferCount()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <template v-if="offers.length > 3">
        <a href="#">View all offers here</a>
    </template>

    <template v-else-if="offers.length > 1">
        <offer v-for="offer in offers" :data="offer"></offer>
    </template>

    <template v-else-if="offers.length == 1">
        <offer :data="offers[0]"></offer>
     </template>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button @click="offers.push(123)">Add Offer</button> offerCount: {{ offerCount }}
</div>
```

Comment: Aha! I was missing the update on `mounted`. Can you explain why it’s needed? Also would it be better if I do it in `beforeUpdate` so that if `offerCount` affects the state of other components, they can be updated in the same render? Since `update` is called at the end of the render and updating `offerCount` then could cause a new one?

Comment: You need to run in the `mounted` so it runs for the first time. (And `mounted` is the hook that runs right after it renders for the first time.) About `beforeUpdate` vs. `updated`, in this case, at least in this demo, it won't matter much. The total updates will end up the same. Maybe you can do some more tests in your real scenario. Here's what I used to test: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/fx4sttft/ -- If in doubt, though, definitely go for `beforeUpdate`, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering this based solely on the idea that you want to count instantiations and destructions of `Offer` components.  I'm not sure why you don't just count `offers.length`.  Maybe other things can trigger instantiations.

Have the component emit events on creation and destruction and have the parent track accordingly.

Alternatively (and maybe overkill) you could use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/) and create a store that the `Offer` commits to on creation and destruction.  This means that you don't have to manually attach `@offer-created/destroyed` directives every time you put an `<offer>` in your markup.

Both methods are included in the following example:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    increment(state) {
      state.count++;
    },
    decrement(state) {
      state.count--;
    }
  }
});

const Offer = {
  props: ["data"],
  template: "<div>{{data.name}}</div>",
  created() {
    console.log("Created");
    this.$emit("offer-created");

    this.$store.commit("increment");
  },
  destroyed() {
    console.log("Destroyed");
    this.$emit("offer-destroyed");

    this.$store.commit("decrement");
  }
};

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  components: {
    offer: Offer
  },
  data() {
    return {
      offers: [],
      offerCount: 0
    };
  },
  computed: {
    offerCountFromStore() {
      return this.$store.state.count;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    offerCreated() {
      this.offerCount++;
    },
    offerDestroyed() {
      this.offerCount--;
    },
    addOffer() {
      this.offers.push({
        name: `Item: ${this.offers.length}`
      });
    },
    removeOffer() {
      this.offers.pop();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>Offer instances: {{offerCount}}</div>
  <div>Offer instances (from store): {{offerCountFromStore}}</div>
  <div>
    <div v-if="offers.length > 3">
      <a href="#">View all offers here</a>
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="offers.length > 1">
      <offer @offer-created="offerCreated" @offer-destroyed="offerDestroyed" v-for="offer in offers" :data="offer"></offer>
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="offers.length == 1">
      <offer @offer-created="offerCreated" @offer-destroyed="offerDestroyed" :data="offers[0]"></offer>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button @click.prevent="addOffer">Add</button>
    <button @click.prevent="removeOffer">Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

The problem with trying to use [`$children`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-children) is that it is, inherently, not reactive:

> The direct child components of the current instance. **Note there’s no
> order guarantee for `$children`, and it is not reactive**. If you find
> yourself trying to use `$children` for data binding, consider using an
> Array and `v-for` to generate child components, and use the Array as
> the source of truth.

Comment: I don’t track `offers.length` because if it’s more than `3`, I create no `<offer>` components, so the value I’d be looking for is `0`.

Comment: Your approach is what I’ll use if nothing better pops up. What do you think about `this.$children` + some hook on the parent? A loop that checks `this.$children[i].$options._componentTag`. I’m currently trying to make that work.