# How to get the number of Vue components rendered in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vue-component

I'm building a blog app with a firestore backend, and I am showing the comments that I bring from firestore in a component, the component repeats for each comment ... So far so good.

Now I want to know how many comments there are in the collection of comments, the problem is that bringing the size of the collection `querySnapshot.size` is not recommended because it reads the whole collection, the other way is to use distributed counters, but they are a pain in the butt for a noob like me... Besides, I do not plan to receive so many comments to use a counter.

So, is there a way to get the number of components rendered in the DOM? That way, I don't have to count how many comments are in the collection, because I already have the total comments printed in the DOM.

Comment: If you're already rendering all comments into the HTML, you're already loading all of them from the database, aren't you? In that case, why don't you call `size` in the snapshot right there?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Doesn't count that as another read to the entire collection again?

Comment: Not if you already have the `querySnapshot`. You pay for the construction of a query snapshot, not for the calls on it.

Comment: Perfect, thanks man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already said, you can use `size` from querySnapshot, it won't make an additional read to the collection, since it's only the number of already retrieved documents.

Another way to do it is by counting the number of times the component has been mounted and updated an idea of how to do it is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50048769/5495197):

```
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <p>Number of comments {{comments}}</p>
    <comments-component></comments-component>
    <comments-component></comments-component>
    <comments-component></comments-component>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

```
Vue.component('comments-component', {
  template: '<p>Comment</p>'
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    comments: 0
  },
  methods: {
    updateCommmentCounter() {
      this.comments = this.$children.filter(child => child.constructor.options.name === 'comments-component').length;
    }
  },
  beforeUpdate() {
    this.updateCommmentCounter()
  },
  mounted() {
    this.updateCommmentCounter()
  }
})
```